# Best way to Create a Meme Coin on Solana/Tips?

Tags: token, createminttoinstruction

It looks like you can explained 300 bucks on deck screener to make one. Is it that easy?

Answer (score 1):

Most creators use https://fluxbeam.xyz/

It supports Token Extensions which is the latest.

So I would start wif that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).